Keyboard shortcut panel for Object > Set Origin...?
Is there a quick shortcut to show the Set Origin... panel? Something like Ctrl+A which shows the Apply panel. If not, I'll have to add it to Quick Favorites, although I don't want to fill Quick Favorites with shortcuts if they already exist. Thanks in advance.


Not to my knowledge but it should be on the right-click menu which means you don't need to go up to the Object menu on the menu bar to get to it.

If I press Ctrl->Alt->X I get a pie menu with origin setting options. But, that is from the Blender addon 3D Viewport Pie Menus.

Ah yes. I'd forgotten that one. I think I have that one turned off in the addon options because all the pie menus really annoy me!

Thanks friends, I didn't know that this menu was on the right click, this helps me! Does anyone know how I mark the thread as solved or how I mark the answer that helped me? I can't see any button to mark comments or anything like that. Thanks!
